# Extract x seconds from every minute with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract x seconds from every minute and produce a video.

For example: from a 6 minute video, I want to take the 1st second from the 1st minute, then the 1st second from the 2nd minute etc. (or more clearly, take 00:00:01, 00:01:01, 00:02:01 ...) and construct a new video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select='lt(mod(t,60),1)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" out.mp4
```

If audio's also present, add

```
-af "aselect='lt(mod(t,60),1)',asetpts=N/SR/TB"
```

Comment: One more question: how can i make it dynamic. For example: if i have 120 seconds video and produce a 30 second video. 120/30 = 4 which means to create video from every 4th second? I m trying something like this `lt(mod(t,VIDEO_LENGTH_IN_SECONDS/30),1)` but not sure whats the variable name for the length

Comment: ffmpeg filters can't access video duration. It will have to be precomputed.

Comment: Is it possible to run this comando faster maybe by using -ss lt(mod(t,60),1) or something like this?