# ffmpeg select filter only works properly after conversion to same file format

Tags: ffmpeg, video, vlc-media-player, video-conversion

Could y'all help me figure what's going on? I'm new to ffmpeg but can't find anything about this issue online. This is my first post about coding questions so please let me know if I missed something!

I sampled 5 seconds of video every 5 minutes with the following ffmpeg command adapted from [Extract x seconds from every minute with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1195844/extract-x-seconds-from-every-minute-with-ffmpeg?newreg=3f47b6c965c54b209499bc320b1a9bc6):

```
% ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select='lt(mod(t,300),5)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" out.mp4
```

I noticed it correctly selects the first 5 seconds of video for a total of 20 seconds of selected video only and not the rest (the video itself is 94 minutes). I also noticed that my Mac wasn't able to play the original video on Quicktime (but VLC vers. 3.0.14 can), so I wondered if reconverting it to the same file format would do anything:

```
%  ffmpeg -i in.mp4 in1.mp4
```

I then ran the select command with the new converted in1.mp4 and the resulting out.mp4 was sampled to the correct length!

The issue is "converting" takes a long time, and I have 1512 hours of footage per week to sample and don't have time to convert every video.

original video info

```
% ffmpeg -i in.mp4

ffmpeg version N-102563-gf9eb440e78-tessus https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/ Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
libavutil 57. 0.100 / 57. 0.100
libavcodec  59. 1.100 / 59. 1.100
libavformat 59. 2.100 / 59. 2.100
libavdevice 59. 0.100 / 59. 0.100
libavfilter  8. 0.101 / 8. 0.101
libswscale 6. 0.100 / 6. 0.100
libswresample  4. 0.100 / 4. 0.100
libpostproc 56. 0.100 / 56. 0.100
Input #0, mpeg, from 'in.mp4':
Duration: 01:34:20.84, start: 20011.729711, bitrate: 1503 kb/s
Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: hevc (Main), yuvj420p(pc), 2592x1944, 51 tbr, 90k tbn
```

"converted" video info

```
% ffmpeg -i in1.mp4  

ffmpeg version N-102563-gf9eb440e78-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavcodec     59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
  libavformat    59.  2.100 / 59.  2.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
  libavfilter     8.  0.101 /  8.  0.101
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'in1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.2.100
  Duration: 01:34:20.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4087 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 2592x1944, 4082 kb/s, 51 fps, 51 tbr, 13056 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
At least one output file must be specified
Clearly, the "converted" video has a lot more metadata for some reason?
```

My questions are:

1. Why is the original video not selecting or reading in correctly?
2. Is there a reason why reconverting to the same file format allows ffmpeg to select correctly?
3. Is there a better way to get ffmpeg to select those 5 second samples correctly without having to convert first?

Thanks!

Edit/update: I realized I was converting to h264 from hvec which allowed ffmpeg to use the select filter correctly, but it still doesn't solve the issue with why it's not filtering the original hvec file format correctly.

I've included a -report on the hvec/h.265 file format below as @Gyan has suggested:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GjGmnUErPCIr3qoszXweAA8OiWXdpETg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Add `-report` to `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select='lt(mod(t,300),5)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" out.mp4` and run. Share report.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan - I've updated with a shared report!

Comment: The log shows operation as expected. Totally 950 frames chosen and retimed at 51 fps (the source fps). See the last 40-50 lines of the report.

Comment: For some reason the output of the 94 minute original hvec video is only 19 seconds when it should be around 1.5 minutes. After converting to h264, the output is the correct 1.5 minutes. I'm not sure why the original hvec video is only 19 seconds if the log looks correct... Any ideas on solving this without having to convert to h264 first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the fps is detected as 51 because ffmpeg uses the shortest interframe duration to determine that value, the average fps is 10. For a 94-mn video, there's 19 intervals of 5 mins, so 95 seconds of video to be selected. At 10 fps, that's 950 frames. The output duration is low because ffmpeg uses the detected fps to retime it.

In this case, 10 is a better choice. Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select='lt(mod(t,300),5)',setpts=N/10/TB" out.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you!! That was the issue! I wonder why it detects as 51 fps in h265 vs correctly at 10 fps at h264. Thanks for helping me solve this issue!